# Django how to find view by url

Tags: django

I see a page in django, but i can't find it in the project templates or any folder around it by doing search by string in files, is there a way to find these html templates from a specific page by url? or there is any other way to find them? maybe they are somehow encoded idk...

Comment: Take first part of the url path, go to base folder with urls and see where it leads. Follow the rabbit.

Comment: @gonczor there is no url with that name, thats the problem

Comment: If it's Django you can't use url that is not registered. Show the basic `urls.py` file and url you are struggling with.\

Comment: @gonczor oh i see i found this     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), - but what does this mean, where are the views stored if i see this?

Comment: The entry `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` is adding the urls from the [Django admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/). The views are in `django.contrib.admin`. Note that because the admin app is quite old, the views are defined differently compared to most other apps.

Comment: I don't know why people down voted this question, they must not work in many decades old, Django mega projects where there are over 100 urls.py files spread throughout the codebase with weird non-intuitive regexes. Written by others several careers ago. But I up-voted this as it was a very helpful question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) to get the view function that will handle a view.

```
from django.urls import resolve

match = resolve('/your/url/')
print(match.func)
print(match.url_name)
```

You can then look up the view, and see which template it uses.

You could also use the Django debug toolbar. It has a [templates panel](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html#template) which shows which templates were rendered.

Comment: On Django 1.7, need to use `from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve`